# Solve the recurrence equation T(n) = T(n/3) + O(1) using iteration or substitution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

I realize that solving this with Master's theorem gives the answer of Big Theta(log n). However, I want to know more and find the base of the logarithm. I tried reading about masters theorem more to find out about the base but could not find more information on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

How would I solve this using recursion tree or substitution method for solving recurrences? 
You can assume n = 2^K and T(0) = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `n=2^k` but `n=3^k`

thus `T(3^k) = T(3^{k-1}) + c`

recurrence becomes `w_k = w_{k-1} + c`

Assuming `T(1) = 1`
with the general term: `w_k = ck+1`
and `w_0 = 1`

you conclude `T(n) = clog_3(n) + 1`

and thus `T(n) = O(log_3(n))`

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + O(1) = T(n/9) + O(1) + O(1) = T(n/27) + O(1) + O(1) + O(1) = …
```

After `log3(n)` steps, the term `T` vanishes and `T(n) = O(log(n))`.

Comment: I understand the fact that it takes log3(n) steps to terminate the recursion tree. Does the base of the logarithm here represent the same base of the logarithm in T(n) = O(log(n)) ?

Comment: the base of ```log_3(n)``` is ```3``` and the base of ```log(n)``` is ```e```. You can change the base with ```log_3(n) = log(n)/log(3)```. Now ```O(log_3(n)) = O(log(n)/log(3)) = O(log(n))```

Comment: Big-O doesn't care about a multiplicative constant.